# Adding text before ${user.username} discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I am trying to build a discord bot and I was wondering in my code I have

```js
if (command === 'roast') {
     var roasts = ["option 1", "option 2", "option 3", "option 4"];
     var randomroast = Math.floor(Math.random() * roasts.length);

     if (args[0]) {
        const user = getUserFromMention(args[0]);
        if (!user) {
          return message.reply('Please use a proper mention.');
        }
  
        message.channel.send(`${user.username}`);
        message.channel.send(roasts[randomroast])
     }
}
```

I was wondering if I could edit the text so it puts a `@` infront of the username and puts the roast after the username instead of using 2 lines

Comment: It's a template string, just place text before the injection.

Comment: What have you tried? Why not simply place the text where you'd like it to appear...?

Comment: You can do the following: ```message.channel.send(`@${user.username}${roasts[randomroast]}`);```

Answer (score 1):

***You have one million of ways to make this...***

```js
// The normal way to go...
message.channel.send(`Message Before name ${user.username} Message After name`);

//Others Examples...

let msgBefore = "Before";
let msgAfter = "After";
const nickName = user.username;

message.channel.send(msgBefore + nickName + msgAfter);
//or
message.channel.send("Text-Before " + nickName + " Text-After");
//or
message.channel.send("BEFORE" + `${user.username}` + "AFTER");
//or
message.channel.send(`${msgBefore} ${user.username} ${msgAfter}`);
//Really easy, no?
```

**read the docs, see this example of Concat (you don't need concat but for studying).:**

> [JavaScript - Concat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat)

Answer (score -1):

This is How its Done

```
 message.channel.send(`<@${user.id}> , ${roasts[randomroast]}`);
```